# Angular Material Checkbox Default Value Selection

Tags: angular

there are 4 checkbox data in my modal. I want the previously selected data to be selected when the modal is closed and opened. How can I do this?

I added the selected data to a list, but unfortunately I could not make it selected.

HTML temaplate:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 mt-2"
            *ngFor="let measurementTableList of getMeasurementPointIds()">
     <p>
        <mat-checkbox   [checked]="checkedMeasurmentPointId" value="measurementTableList"
                (change)="checkedMeasurmentPoint(measurementTableList, $event)">
                {{getMeasurementPointName(measurementTableList).measurementPointName}}</mat-checkbox>
     </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

TypeScript:

```
 checkedMeasurmentPoint(selectedPoint: number, event: boolean) {

    if (event['checked']) {
      this.checkedMeasurmentPointId.push(selectedPoint)
    }
    else {
      const index = this.checkedMeasurmentPointId.indexOf(selectedPoint, 0);
      if (index > -1) {
        this.checkedMeasurmentPointId.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }

    this.ref.markForCheck();
  }
```

I tried `[(ngModel)]` but it didn't work

Comment: Remember that you will have to replace the whole array to make angular change detection work. Changes inside an array will not be detected by change detection.

Comment: @MikkelDalby I change the array (change) to add the selected value directly to the array, but when I refresh the page, unfortunately the values I selected are not selected by default.

Comment: if you need the state to be kept when refreshing the page, you will have to store the state. That could be done with local storage or sessionstorage.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the condition for "checked" as shown below,

```
[checked]="checkedMeasurmentPointId.includes(measurementTableList)"
```

Answer (score 0):

assign checked value to true on change function. [checked] value should be boolean, thus element of array checkedMeasurmentPointId, not array itself.

```
<div class="col-md-4 mt-2"
            *ngFor="let measurementTableList of getMeasurementPointIds(); let i = index">
            <p>
              <mat-checkbox   [checked]="checkedMeasurmentPointId[i]" 
              (change)="checkedMeasurmentPoint(measurementTableList,$event)">
   {{getMeasurementPointName(measurementTableList).measurementPointName}}</mat-checkbox>
            </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, I applied your solution, but this time, no matter which value I select, the first value is selected with the value I select.